# golang ginkgo test coverage across packages

Tags: go, testing, code-coverage, ginkgo

I have the following file structure:

```
❯ tree
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── Makefile
├── p1
│   └── p1.go
└── tests
    └── integration
        └── integration_suite_test.go

3 directories, 5 files
```

Where, the `p1/p1.go` has a function:

```
❯ cat p1/p1.go
package p1

func MyTestFunction(s string) string {
        return "hello " + s
}
```

which I am testing from a ginkgo test from a different directory:

```
❯ cat tests/integration/integration_suite_test.go 
package integration_test

import (
        "testing"

        "example.com/test-ginkgo/p1"
        . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2"
        . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
)

func TestIntegration(t *testing.T) {
        RegisterFailHandler(Fail)
        RunSpecs(t, "Integration Suite")
}

var _ = Describe("Testing external function", func() {
        _ = Context("from integration test", func() {
                It("and verify coverage", func() {
                        input := "test"
                        want := "hello " + input
                        got := p1.MyTestFunction(input)
                        Expect(got).To(Equal(want))
                })
        })
})
```

I execute the cases via:

```
$ ginkgo -r -v -race --trace --cover --coverprofile=.coverage-report.out --coverpkg=./... ./...
```

but ginkgo reports that no code coverage and the .coverage-report.out file is empty, even though I have specified `--coverpkg` to include all the directories.

```
❯ cat .coverage-report.out 
mode: atomic
```

Is my expectation wrong and such a coverage across packages not possible with ginkgo ? Or am I doing something wrong ? The `--coverpkg` seems like not doing anything useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed this as a [issue](https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo/issues/995) in the ginkgo repo and the author was graceful enough to point me to the correct way to solve this.

While calling `ginkgo` launch it as below, with the correct full path
(as mentioned in your `go.mod` file) mentioned for the `--coverpkg` parameter and it would work:

```
ginkgo -r -v -race --trace --coverpkg=example.com/test-ginkgo/p1 --coverprofile=.coverage-report.out ./...
```

Now I am able to see the `.coverage-report.out` containing correctly.